# Trouble coming up with a title for PhD dissertation - strategies?

Tags: phd, thesis, advisor

This may be a question that is too open-ended for Academia SE, but I thought I would ask here. I have already consulted some online resources, but the solutions were not that helpful.

How does one come up with a 'good' title for a dissertation? My first attempt at a dissertation title was along the lines of:

> **Developing a [methodological] understanding of [this important phenomenon]**

Understandably, this title was a bit broad and generic. My supervisor suggested I make the title a less generic to help specify the contribution of the dissertation. I'm feeling a bit stymied - titles have never been my specialty.

Would any advisors on this SE be able to share share strategies on how a student can arrive at a successful dissertation titles?

For clarity: this is the 'final' dissertation title.

Comment: Perhaps a name reflecting your main result. "Underwater basketweaving shown to be not optimal"

Comment: Unless the dissertation is about the process of developing something, I would not use "developing" in the title.  And  I would also try to think of a stronger word than understanding.

Comment: I was advised to write a title that no one else could have. Maybe that helps with determining how specific your title needs to be?

Comment: Use more narrow or specific terms.

Comment: From personal experience, it doesn't take very long for even you to not remember your thesis title. I guess I could go look on the shelf to see, but I don't see a need to...

Comment: You can add something like "using XXX" or "considering YYY" to make it more specific. Don't lose too much sleep over this, the title doesn't make or break the thesis.

Comment: Is this the title you have to give at the beginning of the PhD? Or which is written on the handed in thesis? Can you change it? There are places where the initial title can pretty much be changed at will.

Comment: @user151413 this is the 'final' dissertation title. Updated post for clarity.

Comment: @Lewian I am in agreement, but it's one of those things nagging at me!

Comment: In your suggested title, none of the words “developing”, “methodological” and “understanding” are contributing anything. All dissertations develop an understanding of something (and as for “methodological”, you mean as opposed to what? An _un-methodological_ understanding?). If a word in the title can be removed without taking away any information about what the dissertation contains, you should remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly write down a dozen possible titles, in short varied combinations of the key words you'd want someone to use to find your thesis.  Avoid fillers like "developing" and "understanding".

Prune the list and add to it the next day.

Then perhaps look over the list with your advisor.